# how to access object inside an object Array which is inside another array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an array as follows

```
[
 [{"Id":"5","Color":"White"}],
 [{"Id":"57","Color":"Blue"}],
 [{"Id":"9","Color":"Brown"}]
]
```

each object is inside an array which is inside another array. I want to access an object item, let say 'Id' of first object ("Id":"5"). How can I do that?

Comment: What have  you tried?

Comment: Suppose, If you hold the array in a variable called `x`, Then the required element can be fetched by, `x[0][0]["Id"]`

Comment: That's just a regular nested for / foreach. Did you try something first? https://jsfiddle.net/spev9pw6/

Comment: `outerArray[indexOfInnerArray][0].propertyName`

Comment: Very puzzled by where you are stuck. Do you know how to access the *n*th element of an array? If not, please study up on the basics of JavaScript arrays. You say `array[n]`, right? Then you already know how to access the *m*th element of the *n*th element; obviously that would be `array[n][m]`, right? Do you know how to access a field of an object? If not, then please study up on the basics of JavaScript objects. That would be `object.key`, right? Then you already know how to access a field of the *m*th element of the *n*th element--just `array[n][m].key`, right? So what is your problem again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the array is assigned to a variable:

```
var a = [
 [{"Id":"5","Color":"White"}],
 [{"Id":"57","Color":"Blue"}],
 [{"Id":"9","Color":"Brown"}]
];
```

You can do it like this:

```
a[0][0].Id;
```

or

```
a[0][0]["Id"];
```

To get the second object you would do:

```
a[1][0].Id;
```

or

```
a[1][0].["Id"];
```

Answer (score 1):

if it's javascript your object must be named (e.g. x)

Then select the index of the first array (here : 0, 1 or 2)

Then the "small" array content only one item, you have no choice, take 0.

For end, you can pick the property you need, Id or Color.

You have :

```
var myColor = x[1][0]["Color"];
console.log(myColor); //output : Blue
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var obj_c = [
 [{"Id":"5","Color":"White"}],
 [{"Id":"57", "Color": "Blue"}],
 [{"Id":"9","Color":"Brown"}]
];

console.log(obj_c[0][0].Id);
console.log(obj_c[0][0].Color);
```